# Path that contains specific nodes in the middle?

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher, redisgraph

In Cypher you can get path anchored on two nodes f.e.

```
 match path=(a)-[r:rel*1..5]->(b)
 where a.val = 1 and b.val = 2
 return path
```

the question is how can I get paths that contain say node '(x) where x.val = 5' in the middle, instead of all paths

Answer (score 2):

You can add to the where clause

```
AND ANY(x IN nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE x.val =5)
```

to get paths through at least one node that has val=5